# Disable "Are you sure you want to answer your question?" popup on meta discussions

Tags: feature-request, answers, per-site-meta

When you answer your own question on a per-site meta, the following popup appears if you have low reputation (not sure how much):

[image: Are you sure you want to answer your question?]

Note how the post is tagged discussion. The main reason why many people answer own discussion is to contribute their own opinion.

However this popup could (accidentally) discourage new users from contributing their own opinion; this is not what we want.

**I propose we disable the `Are you sure you want to answer your own question?` popup on meta posts tagged [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion).** Optionally, we could disable this popup for *all* meta posts, but that is debatable.

Comment: Usually the OP own opinion is given in the question itself, then others can share their opinions as new answers. At least that's what I'm used to here on MSE.

Comment: @ShadowWizard In my experience, on per-site metas, you create an answer for your own opinion too. That way users can vote separately on the discussion (e.g. is this a real problem we are facing, or is it useless?) and the opinion of the asker.

Comment: Must admit, not familiar enough with per-site meta. Guess it's valid request then, though quite minor.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I guess the reason why they combine it here is because reputation is involved, so there is no doubling up on posts (and hence upvotes).

Comment: probably depends on the per-site meta.  I don't see a lot of this on MSO, but MSO is still a bit different (even if it is split from MSE now).